# Which is Better for calling a stored procedure-Raw SQL query using object manager or cursor object in Django?

Tags: python, django

As mentioned in the Django Documentation, we can execute a stored procedure by using the cursor object like `cursor.callproc('find_all')`.

And i also know that we can also call a stored procedure in Django by this method `model.object.raw("call SPName")`

I would like to know which of these two methods is better in terms of performance,readability,protection from attacks such as sql injection etc and explanation for the given solution.

Comment: using raw you need to generate procedure args by format string, but when you callproc you send the args by second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries), the `model.objects.raw()` method is intended for running queries that return **model instances**.  See this example from the docs:

```
>>> for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
...     print(p)
John Smith
Jane Jones
```

Consequently, if the result of your stored procedure is to be converted into instances of some of your models, you probably should use `raw()`.  Otherwise, you should work with cursor objects because `raw()` will do unnecessary work to convert the result into Django model instances.

Speaking of your other concerns:

- readability: same as above, this depends on whether your procedure returns data to populate model instances;
- protection from attacks: no difference between the two options, as both of them allow for parameter interpolation, which is injection-safe.